# mPDF 6 как сохранить данные из базы данных

Tags: mpdf

Подскажите как вывести в PDF при помощи библиотеке mPDF 6, данные из БД

Comment: Приведите пример вашей реализации, никто код за вас писать не будет

Comment: Мне не надо писать код за меня. Как я понял с библиотеке, что HTML код что после $html = ''; выводится в PDF примеров куча рабочих, но все они примитивные. Можно ли как нибудь вывести данные из БД например из MySQL. Я побывал вставить в $html = ''; php код он не отрабатывает и pdf не формируется пишет, что не знает php тегов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень упрощено:

```
<?php
$html="";
$dataFromDataBase = some_func_to_get_data_from_db();
foreach($dataFromDataBase as $data){
    $html.=$data->some_field." ".$data->some_another_field;
}
$mPDF->output($html);
```

Главный принцип - в переменную `$html` нужно подставлять уже готовые данные с нужной версткой, а не php код.

Comment: Вот я и думаю как это реализовать.

Comment: Запихивайте просто свои данные с версткой в нее

Comment: Вот я и ищу как его запихать, что не понятного? Пишу на MODx. Ваш оооочень простой пример мне не понятен. По читав форум много где видел ваши ответы, боюсь вас в принципе ни кто не понимает. И в данном случаи вообще не понятны ваши ответы, чтобы на что то ответить нужно почитать и понять в чем проблема у тех кто задает вопросы и ищет помощи, вы этого не делаете. Пишите ответы из своего мира и видения.

Comment: Ого, вот это претензия)) А что Вам мешает в переменную `$html` подставить свою верстку? Приведенный мною пример всего лишь некая абстракция, о назначении переменных можно догадаться из их названия. Вы бы хоть пример показали, как пытаетесь заполнить переменную, обновите свой вопрос выше.

Comment: На сайте нету лички. Скажите вашу почту я вам вышлю php. там не все так про100

Comment: Скайп и почта на мэйл.ру (да и вообще все на свете) такие же как мой ник, только маленькими буквами.